# Pagseguro não redireciona cliente após pagamento

Tags: php, redirecionamento

Após o pagamento, o cliente devia ser redirecionado para a página de obrigado que eu configurei, mas não é o que acontece.

Veja, eu peguei uma API, precisei apenas configurar 2 arquivos, entre eles são: `PaymentPagseguro.php` e `PagSeguroConfig.php`.

O cliente paga, eu recebo o pagamento, tá tudo certo, o problema é que não é direcionado para página que configurei neste arquivo `PaymentPagseguro.php`, exatamente neste pedaço de código:

```
$paymentRequest->setRedirectUrl("https://meusite.com/obrigado.php");
```

Veja que, eu recebo alguns erros no console(não visível pro cliente) a respeito da aplicação do Pagseguro, mas nunca desconfiei porquê tudo funciona normalmente, somente o redirecionamento que não funciona.

**Mas veja, os erros que ocorrem no console:**

1. No momento da abertura da página:

   > (2) Bloqueado carregamento de conteúdo ativo mesclado
   >   “http://clicklogger.rm.uol.com.br/qkw_crossdomain.html?appender=&prd=32&grouping=&referrer=https%3A//www.slimpatchbr.com/comprar.php”

   *Isso deve ocorrer porquê meu site é https, mas não acredito ser o problema..*
2. Quando preencho meu e-mail e clico em avançar:

   > GET
   >   https://dna.uol.com.br/service/sample/conn?id=64ef863649064183a7e740d6a2ae259c&sess=&_=1427674714416
   >     403 Forbidden      60ms
   >
   > ---
   >
   > GET
   >   https://dna.uol.com.br/service/sample/conn?id=64ef863649064183a7e740d6a2ae259c&sess=&_=1427674714513
   >     403 Forbidden      42ms
3. Quando finalizo o pagamento e clico em fechar

   > TypeError: this.callback is undefined
   >   ...Token=this.token;},catchCommunicationException:function(){if(window.location.toS...

Bom, mais detalhes, peçam, para mim tá sendo um grande problema, pois na página de obrigado possuo pixels de conversão que não estão sendo ativados.

Comment: se alguém quiser ir mais  afundo nos problemas do log, eu posso indicar a página onde vendo meus produtos(e lá onde ele compra também).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que esteja usando o [`v2`](https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/como-comecar.html), como você não informou como configurou, irei apenas supor a resposta conforme a [documentação](https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/tutorial-da-biblioteca-pagseguro-em-php.html#configuracao)

- Para integração completa [crie o token](https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/integracao/token-de-seguranca.jhtml)

No PHP devemos chamar a classe `PagSeguroPaymentRequest`

```
$paymentRequest = new PagSeguroPaymentRequest();
```

Para adicionar um item ou mais:

```
$paymentRequest->addItem('0001', 'Notebook', 1, 2430.00);  
$paymentRequest->addItem('0002', 'Mochila',  1, 150.99);
```

Informando o endereço do comprador, assim como tipo do frete:

```
$sedexCode = PagSeguroShippingType::getCodeByType('SEDEX');  
$paymentRequest->setShippingType($sedexCode);  
$paymentRequest->setShippingAddress(  
  '01452002',  
  'Av. Brig. Faria Lima',
  '1384',
  'apto. 114',
  'Jardim Paulistano',
  'São Paulo',
  'SP',
  'BRA'
);
```

Caso você já tenha os dados do comprador, poderá informá-los para facilitar o fluxo de pagamento. Desta forma ele não precisará informá-los novamente.

```
$paymentRequest->setSender(  
  'João Comprador',  
  'email@comprador.com.br',  
  '11',  
  '56273440',  
  'CPF',  
  '156.009.442-76'  
);
```

Definindo a moeda a ser utilizada no pagamento.

```
$paymentRequest->setCurrency("BRL");
```

Definindo informações adicionais, que poderão ser utilizadas pelo seu sistema após o fluxo de pagamento no PagSeguro, acredito que o problema possa ser aqui.

```
// Referenciando a transação do PagSeguro em seu sistema
$paymentRequest->setReference("REF123");  
  
// URL para onde o comprador será redirecionado (GET) após o fluxo de pagamento  
$paymentRequest->setRedirectUrl("https://exemplo.com/obrigado.php");  
  
// URL para onde serão enviadas notificações (POST) indicando alterações no status da transação  
$paymentRequest->addParameter('notificationURL', 'http://www.lojamodelo.com.br/nas');
```

É possível adicionar na requisição de checkout parâmetros/informações que, apesar de já terem sido implementados na API, ainda não estão disponíveis em forma de métodos na biblioteca.

```
$paymentRequest->addParameter('senderBornDate', '07/05/1981');
```

Por fim você deve registrar a requisição no sistema do PagSeguro. O retorno do método register, por padrão, será a URL que deverá ser utilizada para redirecionar o comprador para a tela de pagamento no PagSeguro.

A maneira de realizar o redirecionamento do comprador para efetivar o pagamento no PagSeguro após o retorno da chamada ao método register depende da implementação de seu sistema.

```
try {
  $credentials = PagSeguroConfig::getAccountCredentials();
  $checkoutUrl = $paymentRequest->register($credentials); 
} catch (PagSeguroServiceException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Neste ponto devemos usar o `$checkoutUrl`, deve ficar algo como:

```
try {
    $credentials = PagSeguroConfig::getAccountCredentials();
    $checkoutUrl = $paymentRequest->register($credentials);

    echo '<h2>Criando requisição de pagamento</h2>',
        '<p>URL do pagamento: <strong>', $checkoutUrl,'</strong></p>',
        '<p>',

        //Mostra link para pagamento
        '<a title="URL do pagamento" href="', $checkoutUrl,'">',
        'Ir para URL do pagamento.</a></p>';

} catch (PagSeguroServiceException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Se o uso de `PagSeguroConfig::getAccountCredentials` não funcionar é por que provavelmente tem algo errado nos dados do **PagSeguroConfig.php**, mas você pode tentar "manualmente" para verificar a situação:

```
$credentials = new PagSeguroAccountCredentials("vendedor@lojamodelo.com.br",
    "E231B2C9BCC8474DA2E260B6C8CF60D3");

$url = $paymentRequest->register($credentials);
```

`E231B2C9BCC8474DA2E260B6C8CF60D3` é o código de autorização, você também pode setar ele no `PagSeguroConfig::getAccountCredentials`, como descrito nos exemplos, assim:

```
$credentials->setAuthorizationCode("E231B2C9BCC8474DA2E260B6C8CF60D3");
```

Alguns dos demais problemas (erro 403) que ocorrem pode ser por falta do "token" do arquivo pageseguro, configure o arquivo e de preferencia adicione o caminho real para um arquivo de log.

Inicie a configuração normalmente no **PagSeguroConfig.php**:

```
$PagSeguroConfig = array();

$PagSeguroConfig['environment'] = "production"; // production ou sandbox

$PagSeguroConfig['credentials'] = array();
$PagSeguroConfig['credentials']['email'] = "your_pagseguro_email";
```

Este pode ser o ponto que precisa ser corrigido, é necessário o `token` de produção o `appId` e o `appKey`:

```
$PagSeguroConfig['credentials']['token']['production'] = "Token de produçao do pagseguro";
$PagSeguroConfig['credentials']['token']['sandbox'] = "Token do sandbox";
$PagSeguroConfig['credentials']['appId']['production'] = "Seu ID de produção";
$PagSeguroConfig['credentials']['appId']['sandbox'] = "Seu ID de produção";
$PagSeguroConfig['credentials']['appKey']['production'] = "Sua chave de aplicativo para o ambiente de produção";
$PagSeguroConfig['credentials']['appKey']['sandbox'] = "Sua chave de aplicativo para o ambiente sandbox";
```

Configure o log para poder obter detalhes, talvez ajude a encontrar o problema defina `true` em `$PagSeguroConfig['log']['active'] = true;` e o caminho real de um arquivo em `$PagSeguroConfig['log']['fileLocation']`, por exemplo:

```
$PagSeguroConfig['log']['fileLocation'] = '/home/user/www/pagseguro/log.txt';
```

Deve ficar algo como:

```
$PagSeguroConfig['log'] = array();
$PagSeguroConfig['log']['active'] = true;
$PagSeguroConfig['log']['fileLocation'] = '/home/user/www/pagseguro/log.txt';
```

O erro `TypeError: this.callback is undefined` pode ter ocorrido por causa do `(2) Bloqueado carregamento de conteúdo ativo mesclado`, mas não sei exatamente em que ponto ocorre este problema (se é no seu site ou quando já está na página do pagseguro).

Para fazer o download da API para PHP acesse:

- https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/downloads.html#!Bibliotecas

> **Dica:** após o download acesse a pasta *source/examples*, tem todos exemplos necessários para integração via PHP, poderá ser útil

Comment: +1 Pela resposta detalhada! Quem não percebe já tem onde ler sobre o assunto :)

Comment: Veja: http://download.uol.com.br/pagseguro/docs/pagseguro-checkout-lightbox.pdf, na pnultima folha, foi o detalhe que eu havia esquecido(Eventos do Checkout Lightbox)...
Você pode editar sua resposta e acrescentar isso, pois para mim resolveu desta maneira.

Ou seja, eu preciso gerar aquele script, para que em caso de sucesso(pagamento concluido) eu redirecione o cliente, ou caso abort(fechou o meio de pagamento) eu possa fazer algo(como oferecer uma outra oferta..) @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus não que eu discorde da sua solução, pelo contrário, mas eu acho que você mesmo poderia fornecer uma resposta, infelizmente não tem como fornecer a recompensa para ti mesmo, mas você poderia formular uma boa resposta. Eu só não adicionei pois não sei se realmente o lightbox é necessário para o uso com a API em PHP e como nunca usei o lightbox não sei se realmente é necessário. :)

Answer (score 5):

Seguem os passos para lidar com a questão:

1. Acesse o painel de controle do PagSeguro.
2. No menu a esquerda, opção Integrações, Página de Redirecionamento, A. Página fixa de redirecionamento.
3. Insira a URL no campo "Definir página de redirecionamento:" e clique em "Ativar".
4. No menu a esquerda, opção Integrações, Notificação de Transações, insira a URL no campo "Definir URL para receber as notificações:" e clique em "Ativar".
5. No menu a esquerda, opção Integrações,Retorno Automático de Dados,insira a URL no campo  "Definir URL para receber as notificações:" e clique em "Ativar".

Está usando a API nova?

Comment: A URL de redirecionamento não é fixa, pois eu uso uma API e nela eu configurei a página.
Nem poderia ser fixa, já que na mesma conta do Pagseguro atende 2 sites diferentes(2 páginas de redirecionamento diferentes).
E como diz lá: "Você também pode definir uma página de redirecionamento dinâmica via API. Utilizando esse recurso, a página de redirecionamento fixa se preenchida, deixará de funcionar."...

O retorno automático de dados já foi preenchido, o problema não é as notificações, e sim que o cliente não é redirecionado para página de obrigado, definido na API. Obrigado pela ajuda!!

Answer (score 1):

Sobre o primeiro problema, encontrei uma solução no google.

Na sua pergunta você citou:

> Isso deve ocorrer porquê meu site é https, mas não acredito ser o problema..

Nesse [link](https://github.com/jpillora/jquery.rest/issues/15) você pode ver a conversa original.

Segue a resposta dada:

> Fico feliz a sua utilidade para você ! Conteúdo misto normalmente significa
>   que seus arquivos estáticos estão sendo servidos a partir de HTTP e HTTPS,
>   se isso é verdade , você vai precisar para assegurar que todos os arquivos
>   ( e API) está usando HTTPS

Tente isso.

A propósito, já tentou entrar no forum deles [neste link](http://forum.pagseguro.uol.com.br/) ?

Comment: vou tentar, mas o conteúdo bloqueado é do pagseguro, eu acho estranho o pagseguro não deixar claro, ou não fornecer uma API que também acompanhe um servidor seguro(HTTPS), vou tentar realizar uma compra e ver se(agora, com o SSL desativado) funciona normalmente.
Assim como entrei no fórum, deixei minha pergunta lá, e as respostas são as básicas, as padrões, como ativação da API de pagamento nas configurações.. Obrigado pela sugestão, vou testar aqui e volto mais tarde para dizer se funcionou ou não.

Comment: amigo, testado e não funcionou, como disse, duvidava dessa possibilidade, pois se uma API de um meio de pagamento grande peca em relação a sites httpS ao ponto de tirar uma funcionalidade como o redirecionamento.. Enfim, obrigado pela sugestão!!

Comment: Pela minha experiência mesmo empresas grandes pecam muito em documentação de API's. Imagina então sobre isso rs. Bom, você desativou o SSL, a proposta era mudar todos os links e os arquivos estaticos para HTTPS (sim, isso da problema as vezes, por isso que muitos scripts testam se esta com o SSL ativado para adicionar o "S" no http na hora de incluir JS ou CSS). Já tentou isso também? (sem certezas o jeito é tentar)

Comment: Raul, agradecido pela ajuda e pelo conhecimento, dessa vez não funcionou, mas é algo que possa acontecer no futuro e eu agora tenho mais uma opção de como posso resolver, obrigado!